# Setting BIT variable using CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm in the middle of a migration that uses some reporting elements from Crystal and attempting to convert what existed previously into SQL. It looks to use VB scripting but I can't figure out how to make the switch over.

Initially I'd assume a `CASE WHEN` statement would suffice but I can't determine the right logic behind the query.

Sample of the VB below:

```
Dim HasValue As Boolean

If isnull({Reference.Shallow}) Then
    HasValue=False
    formula="MISSING"
Else 
    HasValue=True
End If
```

I am aware that IF does exist in SQL Server but when researching it, people tend to stray away from it as CASE WHEN does the same?

I have some psuedo that I'd imagine should work in the same way but this does not resolve as you cannot set a variable within a `CASE WHEN` statement (I believe):

```
DECLARE HasValue BIT

CASE WHEN Reference.Shallow IS NULL 
THEN SET @HasValue = 1 
ELSE SET @HasValue = 0 
END AS Shallow
```

What would be the most appropriate way of doing this within SQL?

Comment: In SQL `case` is an expression, not a logical flow/branching construct. Try using `set @HasValue = CASE ... END`.

Comment: @Larnu think you mis-read the question, I know ```IF``` exists in SQL!

Comment: I miss read that statement, but not the question, @ExitGame .

Answer (score 2):

You must use this code snippet

```
DECLARE @HasValue BIT

SELECT @HasValue=CASE WHEN Shallow IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS 
BIT) END FROM Reference.Shallow
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` returns a scalar value, not a operation or boolean result. You set the value of the variable to the result of the `CASE`:

```
SET @HasValue = (SELECT CASE WHEN R.Shallow IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                 FROM dbo.Reference R
                 /*WHERE...? */);
```